# Eclipse: Remove "Run As" options

Tags: eclipse

Each time I run a program for the first time in Eclipse, I am prompted to choose between the alternatives
 - **Run on Server**
 - **Java Application**

Now, I might be at fault since I worked with some Tomcat servers through Eclipse a while back, but I cannot for the life of me find out how to remove **Run on Server** as an option. In more than 99% of the cases for me, I would want to run it as a **Java Application**.

Comment: This is project specific, how did you create the project you want to run? Make sure the project facets do not include any Web modules, such as Dynamic Web Module.

Comment: I create all projects the same way, through the creation Wizard. 
On OSX:`Alt`+`cmd`+`n`, choose Java Project, fill in the name and finish. The defaults say nothing about servers or web modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could uninstall the Web Tools (WTP) features, which is what contribute the **Run on server** capability. Open the **About Eclipse** dialog, click the **Installation Details** button and then look for "Eclipse Web Developer Tools" in the **Installed Software** tab.

It might be hard to find depending on what package you started with and how things were added, because any feature can be embedded into others. On my installation, it's under *Eclipse IDE for JEE Developers* > *Java EE IDE Feature*.